# Nested compare() call - possible to change generics information?

Tags: java, generics

```
private interface Internal {
    <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void compare(final T left, T right);
}

private final Internal internal = ...;

public <T> void compare(final Comparable<T> left, final Comparable<T> right) {
    this.internal.compare(left, right);
}
```

I'm seeing a compiler error on `.compare(left, right)`:

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method compare(T, T) of type 
MyClass.Internal is not applicable for the arguments 
(Comparable<T>, Comparable<T>). The inferred type Comparable<T> is not a valid
substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

Is there any reasonable way to accomplish the transition I'm trying to make - taking in Comparable from the public-facing method and using it in a type-safe manner in the internal implementation? Or do I need the same type information for my outer method as I have for the inner one?

Comment: What is the `compare` method meant to do?

Comment: compare(T left, T right) { if (left != null) left.compareTo(right); }     But, as mentioned below, I'm sure that Radiodef is correct. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparable is just defined as:

```
public interface Comparable<T>
```

It means that implementing classes can `compareTo` anything they want. So for example I can do this:

```
class Vague
implements Comparable<String> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(String str) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

When you have a type as:

```
<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

It means that `T` must be a Comparable that also compares to a `T` or superclass of `T`.

On the other hand, when you just have `<T>` and then `Comparable<T>` it can be a Comparable that compares to anything.

The class Vague is a `Comparable<T>` but not a `T extends Comparable<? super T>`. Obviously Vague is not a good Comparable.

So yes, these are inconvertible types and the method signatures will have to be made to match. `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` is the type safe way to declare a Comparable parameter generically. It means two instances of `T` can be compared to each other.

Comment: I realized it was a stupid question on the drive home, but it was too late to unask. :-( Thanks!